# C# compact framework : load a png alpha blending file

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a png image file with alpha blending of its own. Now I want to load it onto a form in a mobile. I tried so many ways but not work. Is there any solution? Thanks in advance.
This is what I use to load the image from resource:

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("drawObj.Graph.png");
Bitmap myPNGImg = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Then create new bitmap with same size of the images Graph.png:

```
Bitmap myBlankImg = new Bitmap(48,48);

Graphics  mynewGraph = Graphics.FromImage(myNew);

mynewGraph.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

Draw the PNG bitmap: `mynewGraph.DrawImage(myPNGImg, 0, 0);`
And then something I read from internet:(

```
Rectangle rectDest = new Rectangle(50,50, 100, 100);

ImageAttributes imgatt = new ImageAttributes();

imgatt.SetColorKey(Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent);

myGraph.DrawImage(myNew, rectDest, 0, 0, 99, 99,GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgatt);
```

It works, but just clear the four corner of the images(somekind of rounded rectangle). There's still some white border around the images left.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code...

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with CF, and its graphic limitations, I'll just add this as a comment : the usual source of unwanted "fringes" in a png with alpha is creation of the png with anti-alisasing on. There's an article on CodeProject that goes into this (in the context of using LayeredWindow [WS_EX_LAYERED] in WinForms) in depth : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AlphaForm.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading images using Bitmap on Compact Framework will lose alpha information. Setting the color key is an alternative way of doing transparency where you sacrifice an exact single color as the transparent color.

To use alpha blending on Compact Framework, you can use the helper classes from OpenNETCF to load the PNG file, keeping the alpha information (see [Transparency and alpha blending](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2006/02/03/new-in-opennetcf-sdf-2-0-imaging-api-wrapper-part-ii/)), then P/Invoke [AlphaBlend](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrislorton/archive/2006/04/07/570649.aspx). It's not pretty, but it's what it takes. Also be warned that you will take a heavy performance hit for using alpha blending. To bake some images dynamically, it's fine, but for generic on screen drawing operations, you might want to use another approach.

Comment: Im not trying to make transparent all my png image. I just need to clear all the transparence in my png image and draw the left image on to the form. So do I have to do the step P/Invoke AlphaBlend as you told?

Comment: As someone pointed out (and then deleted their comment?), that issue likely comes from an antialiased image, where parts of the image is not fully transparent, nor fully opaque. The method you're using only handles the cases there there is an single exact color to use for representing transparent parts of the image. If that's all you need, you can get away with just fixing up the image first using your favourite image manipulation program.

Comment: Problem here is that Im not allowed to edit the images and I can't import the OpenNetCF either. Any other way? Thanks

Comment: Do whatever OpenNetCF does to load the images (source is available) and flatten it once when you load the image (or use AlphaBlend). If you know the background the image is to be painted on, the most efficient way is probably to AlphaBlend once into a new bitmap, then paint that without any transparency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the CF, filling with Color.Transparent actually fills with white (see [these two](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/10/26/ProjectResistanceTransparencyInTheCompactFrameworkSucks.aspx) [blog entries](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/10/28/ProjectResistanceDay4GraphicFixesAndMoreGesturing.aspx)). [Project Resistance](http://resistance.codeplex.com) has a very good example of how to do this blending (actually several of them).

Comment: good example, not only for imaging processing, use of custom attributes.